# How do i pass an array of structs by reference to a function?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, pass-by-reference, swap

I need to write a function that would reflect an image by having ever pixel in the image with in a 2D array of structs. Below is the function i have written which basically switches the last pixel with the first pixel and so on but i need it to edit the original array and not a copy which is what its currently not doing. Below is the function within main and how the function is laid out. Any input would help!

```
reflect(height, width, &image);
```

Function:

```
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE *image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++)
    {
        for( int j = 0 ; j < width ; j++)
        {
            temp = image[i][j];
            image[i][j] = image[i][width-j-1];
            image[i][width-1-j]=temp;

        }
    }
}
```

And the struct is as shown below

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

The array of structs is created using this:

```
    // Allocate memory for image
    RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
```

Comment: Don't use a 2D structure, use a 1D structure. It's much, much easier to work with. In this case the compiler cannot use one argument to dictate the type of another.

Comment: @tadman Im currently doing the CS50 course and thats what they require us to do. I've tried it in a 1D structure and it works but i need to make it work using this method.

Comment: On further reflection, why not treat this as a raw byte array and just navigate it correctly using offset calculations and some `memcpy`?

Comment: `j < width/2` or you reflect twice

Comment: Ah, CS50 strikes again. You can do this as `RGBTRIPLE**` if you have an array of pointers to the various rows.

Comment: @tadman How would that work within the function? At the implementation within main should i keep the "&"? I tried every method but im still getting compilier errors

Comment: In C, when you pass an array to a function, it's always converted to a pointer to its first element, so they're effectively passed by reference.

Comment: You need to compose the structure specifically to be handled that way. It requires allocating `height` times row arrays. You'll need to show the code that creates that structure and how it passes it in.

Comment: It's better to edit your question and include that with the rest of the code than dump it in as a comment.

Comment: @tadman Just edited the post

Comment: That is a very strange definition. Is that how you were told to do it, or is that your interpretation?

Comment: Paste actual code. The `RGBTRIPLE *image[height][width]` in the function declaration nominally declares a two-dimensional array of pointers to `RGBTRIPLE`, but the code `temp = image[i][j];` in the function assigns an array element to an `RGBTRIPLE`, which will yield a compiler error. Possibly you crafted some “example” code from your actual code, but it is wrong. Construct a proper [mre]. That should include the code that calls the function and a complete demonstration program. The claim a copy is edited is unlikely given an array cannot be passed by copy. Show real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the function should be declared either like

```
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]);
```

or like

```
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[][width]);
```

or like

```
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE ( *image )[width]);
```

and called like

```
reflect(height, width, image);
```

Within the function the loop should look like

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++)
{
    for( int j = 0 ; j < width / 2 ; j++)
    {
        temp = image[i][j];
        image[i][j] = image[i][width-j-1];
        image[i][width-1-j]=temp;

    }
}
```